# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{a+ix}}{a^2+x^2}\,dx$ using residue calculus

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration, solution-verification, residue-calculus

I'm asked to evaluate 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{a+ix}}{a^2+x^2}\,dx$$
$\mathbb{R}\ni a>0$, using residue calculus (where $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is the PV $\sqrt{}$). My approach is as follows:

By solving $a+iz=-\alpha, \mathbb{R}\ni\alpha>0$ we find that the branch cut of $\sqrt{a+ix}$ is the line $ia+i\alpha$.

Then we verify that $\lim_{R\to\infty}\max_{|z|=R}\frac{\sqrt{a+iz}}{a^2+z^2}R=0$

From these $2$ facts we can conclude that we can close the contour in the bottom half plane, and find
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{a+ix}}{a^2+x^2}\,dx=-2\pi i\text{Res}_{z=-ai}\frac{\sqrt{a+ix}}{a^2+x^2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{\sqrt{a}}$$

However, the problem is that when I try to verify this using Mathematica, it seems to be wrong:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[a + I*x]/(a^2 + x^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
ConditionalExpression[-(1/(  8 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[a] \[Pi]^(   3/2)))(MeijerG[{{1/2, 3/4, 5/4}, {}}, {{0, 1/2, 1/2}, {}}, -1, 2] +     MeijerG[{{1/2, 3/4, 5/4}, {}}, {{0, 1/2, 1/2}, {}}, 1,      2]), (Re[a^2] >= 0 || a^2 \[NotElement] Reals) && Re[a] > 0]
```

At first I thought this is just some way to complicated way of writing $\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{\sqrt{a}}$, but that does not seem to be the case. For example for $a=2$ my answer is $\pi$ while Mathematica's answers is $3.965.. +0.491...i$. Now I would think my answer is correct, since the imaginary part of the function is odd, so we would expect the integral to have imaginary part $0$.

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm looking for either: the mistake in my answer, or an explanation for why Mathematica is giving the wrong answer.

Thanks.

---

Edit: I'm pretty sure this is a bug in Mathematica at this point, especially considering the following result:

```
a = 2;
N[Integrate[Sqrt[a + I*x]/(a^2 + x^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
NIntegrate[Sqrt[a + I*x]/(a^2 + x^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
3.96542 + 0.491097 I
3.14159 + 0. I
```

So the numeric solver does agree with my answer, while the symbolic solver just seems to be wrong. Unfortunate; I didn't expect Mathematica to have bugs like this, although I think it's inevitable in an application that big.

Comment: According to *Mathematica*, $I(a)~=~\pi~\sqrt{1+\dfrac1a}~.~$ *Maple*, however, agrees with your result.

Comment: @Lucian What version of Mathematica are you using? I'm using 10 and got the output I mention in the question.

Comment: Version $5$. :-$)$

Comment: i get $I(a)=\frac{(1+i) \pi }{\sqrt{a}}$ which agrees quite well with numerical calculations

Comment: @tired Using what program/reasoning do you get that result?

Comment: Mathematica 10
Integrate[Sqrt[x + I a ]/(x^2 + a^2), {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> a > 0]

Comment: @tired that's not the correct integral though. The $x$ is multiplied by $i$, not the $a$.

Comment: Oh Shit, i'm so sorry for that...now our [mathematica] calculations agree. I will try to solve this by hand tomorrow....

Comment: @tired No problem. I hope you find the flaw in my reasonig and take away my dissapointment in Mathematica:p. Although I'm pretty sure there no way around it; Mathematica is just wrong, especially considering my last edit.

Comment: Ok, i can't resist to give a few comments right now:
-First of all, Mathematica is very shitty with complex numbers in integration problems
-Numerical checks suggest that you are right
-Your reasoning seems to be absolutly valid

Conclusion: Don't trust Mathematica

Comment: In case you need further confirmation: Your computation of the integral via the residue theorem is correct.